# Can I run sbt new command with a template hosted in private git (not GitHub)?

Tags: sbt

Is it possible to host the template in private Git and run `sbt new` like below

```
sbt new ssh://my-private-git/my-template.g8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 questions:

Is it possible to use it in a non-Github repo?

According to the Docs it is:

> Giter8 is a command line tool to generate files and directories from templates published on Github or any other git repository. ([Giter8](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/index.html#Giter8))

Is it possible to host it in a private Git repo?

Again according the Docs it is:

> Giter8 will use your ssh key to access private repositories, just like git does. ([Private Repositories](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/usage.html#Private+Repositories))

Check [Usage](http://www.foundweekends.org/giter8/usage.html#Usage) on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to run giter8 with private repo but I am trying to use the template with sbt command similar to how we do using giter8 so that it can be used as 
sbt new <privaterepo>/<template>

Comment: Yes i tried yesterday and it worked. I was about to post the solution here but saw u recommend same. Thanks

Comment: This correctly identifies two questions, yet only answers one of them. Also a 10x improvement on "See the manual:" for an answer would be "YES, see the manual:".